# How to show second and third row column values in first row as column values in sql

Tags: sql

I have situation where I have to show second & third row column values in first row as column values at the End.

```
OrgCode  | OrgType
------   | ------
001902001| 5
001902005| 5
001902000| 4
001903000| 4

 Id  | OrgType  | materialId | materialCount
 --- |  ------  | -----------| -----------
  1  |  5       | 793167     |  3
  2  |  5       | 793257     |  3
  3  |  5       | 794808     |  3
  4  |  4       | 793167     |  10
  5  |  4       | 793257     |  10
  6  |  4       | 794808     |  10
```

Based on these two tables I need the final Output as shown below :

```
OrgCode  | OrgType | Item1 | Count1 | Item2 | Count2 | Item3 | Count3
------   | -------   -----   ------   ------- -------  ------  ------
001902001| 5        | 793167 | 3     | 793257 | 3     | 794808 | 3
001902005| 5        | 793167 | 3     | 793257 | 3     | 794808 | 3  
001902000| 4        | 793167 | 10    | 793257 | 10    | 794808 | 10
001903000| 4        | 793167 | 10    | 793257 | 10    | 794808 | 10
```

Any one please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your requirement doesn't seem right to me MaterialID 793167 can match only OrgType 5, I see that being matched with even 4, which doesn't seem logical

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server and PostgreSQL are very different products. I've removed the tags. Please tag only the one DBMS you are using.

Comment: As to the problem: I suggest you don't use SQL for this, but use your app instead to handle this (a simple loop in Java, C#, PHP or whatever you are using).

Comment: If we do INNER JOIN on the above two tables we will be getting 12 record. Based on these data in app i can handle it but I am checking is there any way to get it at query level itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes up often in the forums and it is understandable since SQL is not built to do this pivot-table/crosstab functionality people find so useful. A good way forward is to move the data somewhere where it is natural, like a spreadsheet or a data manipulation language such as R / python / Julia. In any case, it is possible to do it inside Postgresql using the `tablefunc` extension. The query looks complicated, but it is instructive and if you have to stay inside Postgresql (which is convenient) then this is the way to go:

```
CREATE extension tablefunc ;

-- table are called table1 and table2

SELECT tt.orgcode,
       ss.orgtype,
       item1,
       count1,
       item2,
       count2,
       item3,
       count3
FROM 
    crosstab($$ select 
        a.orgcode, 
        'item'||row_number() over (partition by a.orgcode order by b.materialid) as name, 
        b.materialid 
    from table1 a,table2 b where a.orgtype=b.orgtype $$) AS 
        tt(orgcode integer, item1 integer, item2 integer, item3 integer),
    crosstab ($$ select 
        a.orgcode, 
        'count'||row_number() over (partition by a.orgcode order by b.materialid) as name, 
        b.materialcount 
    from table1 a, table2 b where a.orgtype=b.orgtype $$) AS
        qq(orgcode integer, count1 integer, count2 integer, count3 integer),
    table1 ss
WHERE tt.orgcode=qq.orgcode
  AND tt.orgcode=ss.orgcode
ORDER BY orgtype DESC,
         tt.orgcode;
```

The `crosstab` function takes a table with three columns, say, `A` `B` `C` and creates a table with first column `A` and the values of `B` as further columns, and the value of `C` as the content of the records. The query invokes `crosstab` twice for the item codes and the counts.

The output is nicely:

```
 orgcode | orgtype | item1  | count1 | item2  | count2 | item3  | count3 
---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
 1902001 |       5 | 793167 |      3 | 793257 |      3 | 794808 |      3
 1902005 |       5 | 793167 |      3 | 793257 |      3 | 794808 |      3
 1902000 |       4 | 793167 |     10 | 793257 |     10 | 794808 |     10
 1903000 |       4 | 793167 |     10 | 793257 |     10 | 794808 |     10
(4 rows)
```